# Matlab: Efficient mapping of integer label matrix values to new values using a map

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to map all entries of a 2D matrix containing integer label values to new values using a map. Here is a toy example:

```
a = randi(4,3,3)      % Initial matrix with random values between 1 and 4
b = zeros(size(a))    % Initialization of output matrix
map_old = (1:4);      % Old label values
map_new = [1 1 2 2];  % New label values

% Loop through all new labels and replace old values with new ones using 'ismember' function
for i = 1:max(map_new)
    label_idx = map_new == i;
    label_selected = map_old(label_idx);
    b(ismember(a,label_selected)) = i;
end
```

I guess this is not the most efficient way to do this. Is there any trick or any existing function to do this more efficiently in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexing:

```
b = map_new(a)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know one could use indexing like this. Thx